# Handle 4 dimensional array python

Tags: python, matrix, size, rgb

I want to create a list of 10 matrix (32,32,3) that will contain a sum of values from my RGB images.

So I used `matrixSum = np.zeros((10,32,32,3),np.uint64)`
And I thought to access it using `matrixSum[indiceClass][ligne][col][rgb]`
But I keep having an error telling me that matrixSum[indiceClass] is only size 1
[image]
So I changed my code to `matrixSum[indiceClass][0][ligne][col][rgb]` and I do not have this error anymore but it brings me troubles later.

Am I doing something wrong? It don't understand why I would have an array of size 1 in the middle instead of 32. Or is it logical?
Here is the full code of the function : *(indiceclasse will only be between 0 and 9)*

```
def createMatrixSum(data, nbImagesParClasse):
    matricesSum = np.zeros((10,32,32,3),np.uint64)
    indiceClasse = 0
    for i in range(0,80):
        indiceClasse = data["y"][i]
        indiceClasse -= 1;
        nbImagesParClasse[indiceClasse] += 1
        for ligne in range(32):
            for col in range(32):
                for rgb in range(3):
                    matricesSum[indiceClasse][ligne][col][rgb] += data["X"][ligne,col,rgb,i]
    return matricesSum, nbImagesParClasse
```

Edit : here is the len and shape of my data/matrix before the error.
 [image]
I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Left hand side seems ok, can you check len/shape of `data`.

Comment: Added information on len and shape. But what I find strange is that matrixSum[indiceClass][0][ligne][col][rgb] is working even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that the "indiceClass" I tried to obtain was not an integer as I thought but a list of size 1.
So using it as an index added another list into my matrix which explain why I got that list into the middle. Should have checked that beforehand.